# Is "I do drink" a strange form of the Present Simple?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, present-simple, emphasis

Can I say "I **do** drink a cup of tea"? it is Macmillan student's book. There is a multiple choice exercise that you need choose the correct tense for a sentence

> "Actually, I _______  a cup of tea first thing every morning, but then i switch to coffee"
>
> a) do drink b) am drinking c) have drunk d) have been drinking.

I know that the correct answer is a) - *do drink*, but I have never seen this form of present simple like "do + verb" in a statement sentence. Is it correct?

Answer (score 5):

The use of the auxiliary 'do' in conjunction with a positive verb form is used for emphasis, usually to correct a corresponding negative sentence.

Consider the following example:

> Other person: You don't drink tea, do you?!

> You: Actually, I do drink tea - first thing every morning.

As you may appreciate, the auxiliary is used for emphasis in correcting the other person's statement. As such, when speaking, you would emphasise the auxiliary.

> I *do* drink tea actually.

Remember to modify your auxiliary accordingly:

> He didn't go to his appointment yesterday.

> He *did* go to his appointment actually.

In the case of needing to correct with emphasis with modal verbs, we simply put the emphasis on the modal verb:

> John can't speak Spanish.

> Yes, he *can*

Comment: And this usage is called, not surprisingly, the [**emphatic do**](https://www.callanschool.info/en/free-english-resources/the-emphatic-do-2).